# Is Brans-Dicke theory really ruled out by solar system tests?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, gravity

[Brans-Dicke theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brans%E2%80%93Dicke_theory) with small values of parameter $w$ are said to be ruled out by solar system general relativity tests like the Shapiro time delay test and the deflection of starlight by the sun.

But the calculations based on Brans-Dicke theory assume the Sun is alone in an empty universe. This is not a reasonable assumption as the dilaton field is long range so it should be determined by cosmological considerations. Another [commenter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/12945/22307) on this site has raised a similar query.

However I calculate that if the Brans-Dicke theory is applied to the universe as a whole then one gets a [spatially uniform dilaton field $\phi \sim t$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/537727/brans-dicke-vacuum-cosmology) that varies only slowly with the age of the universe $t$. Where $\phi$ is defined in https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0604082v4 as the square root of the standard Brans-Dicke scalar.

Crucially I assume that $\phi \sim a$. I assume that the change of scale $a(t)$ of the universe is entirely due to the change of the mass scale due to $\phi$.

In that case one can see from the [field equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brans%E2%80%93Dicke_theory#The_field_equations) with $\phi$ derivatives set to zero that the Brans-Dicke theory applied to the solar system predicts the same effects as standard general relativity even for low values of parameter $w$.

Comment: Just to fill in more information, how did you arrive at the constant dilaton field part? If this comes from literature you should include it.

Comment: To me it looks like you got spatial homogeneity out because you put spatial homogeneity in. Did you check that the field is also uniform for perturbed FLRW?

Comment: I just used the Brans-Dicke cosmological equations derived in https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0604082v4

Comment: If that paper is not doing cosmological perturbation theory (and I do not see evidence that it is), then it is really just specifying how the spatially averaged value of the field evolves.